# How to find the email id for the user, with the latest push, for a specific file name?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, git-log

I need to find the email id for the person who pushed a specific file "xyz.txt" to a git repo.

Using `git log` command i get the log for all the commits, however i need to find the email id, based on the file name.

Is there any specific command or JGit API method, which could perform such a task?

Comment: `git log <filename>` will show you commit history for just a specific file; you could probably parse the email out of the Author field.  But posting as a comment because there's probably a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a `git log` (and frankly, most git commands) to a specific file by separating the command from the file with `--`. From there on, it's just a bit of formatting:

```
$ git log -n1 --format="%ae" -- somefile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It just did what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not for JGit, but for command line:

```
git log -1 --format='%ae' -- <filename>
```

PS. Git doesn't remember who's pushed what, it only remember authors (who created code) and committers (who committed the code into the repository). Format `%ae` prints author's email.